# Pushing input values from ng-repeat into array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` displaying a list of **products** with an input each.
I want to be able to push the value of each input together with a parameter from every item into a new array to create an order.

So far I managed to do it individually, but not all together.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products">
  <div>
    <h2>{{pa.nom}}</h2>
    <input type="number" ng-model="basket" min="0" max="20" step="1" ng-init="basket=0">
  </div>
</div>
<a ng-click="insert(pa.nom,basket)">Add items</a>
```

And the function:

```
$scope.singleorder = [];

$scope.insert = function(nom, basket){
  $scope.singleorder.push({
    'product': nom,
    'number': basket
  });
  console.log($scope.singleorder);
}
```

I assume the issue has to do with keeping track of the different models of the inputs on each repeat, but I don't know how to deal with it.

I've also tried adding each item individually using `ng-change` on the input, but it will push an object on every change, duplicating the item on every change, so it won't work.

Any tips?

Comment: Is your `add items` button inside ng-reapeat ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra no it isnt.

Comment: Then how do you decide which item you are pushing to the array?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra that's the issue I think. I want to push them all, one object for each item, containing name (nom) and quantity (basket).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick would be to have an input **for each** repeated element in `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products">
    {{pa.nom}}
    <input type="number" ng-model="pa.basket">
</div>
<a ng-click="insert()">Add items</a>
```

`insert()` will loop over products and insert in `singleOrder` when basket has been set:

```
$scope.insert = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.products[i].basket) { // if input has been set
            $scope.singleorder.push({
              'product': $scope.products[i].nom,
              'number': $scope.products[i].basket
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fgc21e86/13/)

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work. It pushes one single object into the array, when the desired result is to have an object for each product.

Comment: @EricMitjans Try this Fiddle, it is an example of my first solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fgc21e86/12/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

- The first way is to mutate the products collection by adding the quantity property.
- The other way is to keep a separated collection that keeps track of the quantity.

HTML (way 1):

> ```
> <div ng-repeat="pa in products">
>   <div>
>     <h2>{{pa.nom}}</h2>
>     <input type="number" ng-model="pa.quantity" min="0" max="20" step="1">
>   </div>
>   <a ng-click="insert(pa)">Add items</a>  
> </div>
> ```

Javascript (way 1):

> ```
> $scope.singleorder = [];
>
> $scope.insert = function(pa){
>   $scope.singleorder.push({
>     'product': pa.nom,
>     'number': pa.quantity || 0
>   });
>   console.log($scope.singleorder);
> }
> ```

HTML (way 2):

> ```
> <div ng-repeat="pa in products">
>   <div>
>     <h2>{{pa.nom}}</h2>
>     <input type="number" ng-model="productsQunatity[pa.nom]" min="0" max="20" step="1">
>   </div>
>   <a ng-click="insert(pa.nom,productsQunatity[pa.nom])">Add items</a>  
> </div>
> ```

Javascript (way 2):

> ```
> $scope.singleorder = [];
> $scope.productsQunatity = {};
>
> $scope.insert = function(nom){
>   $scope.singleorder.push({
>     'product': nom,
>     'number': $scope.productsQunatity[nom] || 0
>   });
>   console.log($scope.singleorder);
> }
> ```

Keep in mind that you should probably avoid the duplications. So, i propose to check if you already have already a product with the specific id.

> ```
> $scope.insert = function(pa) {
>   var product = $scope.singleorder.find(function(product) {
>     return product.nom === pa.nom;
>   });
>
>   if (product) {
>     product.number += pa.quantity || 0;
>   } else {
>     $scope.singleorder.push({
>       'product': pa.nom,
>       'number': pa.quantity || 0
>     });
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Intialize a array and push a empty dictionary every time you click add more

```
$scope.products = [];
$scope.addNew = addNew;
function addNew(){
  $scope.products.push({});
}
```

And you html would look like this

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products">
    <input type="number" ng-model="pa.basket">
</div>
```

You can put validation over add button, that do not add more until you entered value in previous.

It will automatically form a json in the format of

```
[{
   basket : 'value'
}]
```